# state with 2 dimentional array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to have a 2 dimensional array for the state. Once a user clicks on a touch area. It will update a value in this 2 dimensional array. For some reason, I got error with my code. The following are the constructor and the onPress function

```js
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(Props){
      super(Props);
      this.state = {
        test: 'U',
        array: [
          ['n','n','n'],
          ['6','n','n'],
          ['n','n','n'],
        ]
      };
    }

    onPress = (row,colum) => {
      this.setState({
        array[row][colum]: this.test
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.middleWrapper}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.child]} onPress={this.onPress(1,0)}><Text>  {this.state.array[1][0]}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      );
    }
}
```

It seems the onPress method is not right. But I do not know what is not right. Please help. Thanks.

**

### Update 1:

**

get the error:

```
\node_modules\react-native\scripts\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (38:11)

  36 |   onPress = (row, column) => () => {
  37 |     this.setState({
> 38 |       array[row][colum]: this.test
     |            ^
  39 |     })
  40 |   }
  41 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unexpected token syntax error is from the object in your setState call. The key needs to be wrapped in another set of square brackets:

```
this.setState({
    [array[row][column]]: this.test 
  })
```

This doesn't solve the problem, though.

```
// Create a copy of the state array so that you don't mutate state.
const array = [...this.state.array];

// Update the copy with the new value.
array[row][column] = this.test;

// Replace the state array with the new copy.
this.setState({ array });
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
//In your onPress method there is no variable called array

// First get a soft copy of that array
let  array  = [...this.state.array];

// Do required modification
array[row][colum] = this.test;

// Set modified array in state
this.setState({array:array});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference of a function in onPress, what you're doing will call the onPress function when the component renders. change your code like this

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.child]} onPress={() => this.onPress(1,0)}>
    <Text>{this.state.array[1][0]}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I updated my code, but I got error with the onPress function. Please see my update 1 in the original post.

Comment: that's an syntax error, change your onPress method like I have shown here https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-williams-pqi9z?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the function on the `onPress` prop rather than providing a callback.

`onPress` prop is similar to an `onClick` event handler, you need to provide a function to it.

You can edit your function to return a callback by currying, that way the arguments you send are still in scope for the callback when it gets invoked `onPress`

```
onPress = (row, column) => () => {
  const array = [...this.state.array]; 
  // I use JSON stringify to completely clone complex objects
  // const array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.array));
  array[row][column] = this.test;

  this.setState({ array })
}
```

Or as suggested by the other user send an anonymous function using

```
onPress={() => this.onPress(1, 0)}
```

**Extra Note:** It's better if the state variables are not mutated, this might not be a problem for minimal components but as the component get's complicated it's something that has to be looked into for performance.

Comment: I updated my code as you mentioned. I got the following error:  Please see my update 1 in my original post. I think there is something wrong with my onPress function.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only concentrated on the callback part of it, your `setState` need to set the actual array. Updated the code snippet.